# How shall I understand dependency propagated?

Tags: package-management, dependencies, nixos, nix, terminology

https://nixos.org/manual/nixpkgs/stable/#ssec-stdenv-dependencies-reference says

> A dependency is said to be propagated when some of its other-transitive (non-immediate) downstream dependencies also need it as an immediate dependency

What do "downstream" and "upstream" dependencies mean?

What are "non-immediate" and "immediate" dependencies?

Is the concept of a dependency propagating about the dependent relationship between the dependencies of a package?

Could you explain using an example or diagram?

Comment: I am closing this since [the cross-post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77495377/1081936) is more detailed.

Comment: @terdon seems https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/761877/70524 is also covered by that cross-post

Answer (score 1):

To make shorter, A,B,C stand for package A, package B, package C.

If A depends on B, it means that some code in A gets some external references defined in B.

Let's have A depending on B, itself depending on C.

With regards to B, A can be said ***upstream*** (some also call A a ***backward dependency*** of B) and C ***downstream***.

B can be said an ***immediate*** dependency of A.
But because B depends on C, C can be said a ***non-immediate***  dependency of A since, in this precise case, C does not define any one of A's external references.
A depends on C per virtue of ***transitivity*** (in the mathematical meaning A -> (in some relation with) B -> C => A -> C)

Now let's imagine that A also depends on C.
You can think of the glibc as the most common example. (since it is highly probable that some code of A will call some glibc functions when other libraries A depends on would also depend on the glibc.

You would then have C being an immediate dependency of both A and B. In this case, the dependency on C is said ***propagated***.

A difficult case can arise and lead to some

> obscure / confusing

computation calculus : when A -> B -> C -> D -> B

B, immediate dep on A, is also an immediate dep of D being a non-immediate dep of B. which results in (as quoted from the page linked in OP) in

> sort of a transitive closure of the dependency relation

Comment: Thanks. What would you call, when C is propagated with respect to A and B? Is my understanding of the definition correct: C is said to be propagated from B to A, if B is an immediate dependency of A, and C is of both A and B?

Comment: @Tim : C is not formally said "propagated from B to A". Analysing the (immediate) deps of A, the package-manager will discover B and C. B will come next and C will once again be discovered. C will be said propagated (period). In fact it will just increase counters. In the §Reference of the page you link to, you can discover that it becomes more complex if host and target systems are different.

Comment: @Tim : In fact, the major point for the package-manager is to determine in which order the packages should be built.

Comment: How is "propagate" here related to its original meaning?

Comment: "A dependency is said to be propagated when some of its other-transitive (non-immediate) downstream dependencies also need it as an immediate dependency". in your example, C is propagated, but A is an upstream dependency of C.

Comment: @Tim : OK, I had made short since usually 3 elements are sufficient for explaining transitivity . Let's now consider A -> B -> C -> D -> B. B is a dependency that is said propagated since D, one of B's downstream non immediate dep immediately depends on B. (I can update my answer if necessary)

Comment: So does dependency propagated assume a dependency cycle?

Comment: @Tim : That is indeed what we can read in the §Reference part of the page you linked : "This results is sort of a transitive closure of the dependency relation"

Answer (score 1):

> What do "downstream" and "upstream" dependencies mean?

As in [MC68020’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/761592/86440), I’ll use packages A, B, and C, where A depends on B which depends on C:

A → B → C (in dependency terms).

“Upstream” and “downstream” terminology refer to the stream of changes.

- In a distribution context in general, “upstream” usually refers to the original source of a project provided in a package: changes are made there, then the package is updated to provide the updated project.
- In the context of dependencies specifically, if C changes, then B might need to change, and then A might need to change. Thus C is an upstream dependency of B, and B is an upstream dependency of A; A is a downstream dependency of B, and B is a downstream dependency of C.

> What are "non-immediate" and "immediate" dependencies?

Immediate dependencies are those directly depended upon: B is an immediate dependency of A, C is an immediate dependency of B. Non-immediate dependencies are transitive dependencies: C is a non-immediate dependency of A, because A only depends on C because of B. If A were changed to no longer depend on B, it would also no longer depend on C.

> Is the concept of a dependency propagating about the dependent relationship between the dependencies of a package?

Propagating dependencies reflect *changes* in the dependency tree. Starting from

A → B → C

above, if A is changed to use some features of C, then it becomes directly dependent on C:

A → B → C
A → C

From C’s perspective, its formerly non-immediate dependency A now needs it as an immediate dependency, so the dependency has “propagated”. The propagation isn’t tied to C or the dependency tree, it’s the result of changes in A.

It’s important to pay attention to such changes, because they can go unnoticed. Thanks to B’s dependency on C, A gets access to C’s features “for free”; so when A starts using C directly, no packaging change is needed, and A continues building as usual. However the list of immediate dependencies in A is now incomplete, and if B later on drops its dependency on C, A will stop building even though nothing changed in A.

Comment: Thanks. (1) If A->B->C, why "when A starts using C directly, no packaging change is needed"? Is it because C has been already included in the list of dependencies of A, due to B depending on C? (2) When A->B, "B is an immediate dependency of A". When  "dependency" is mentioned without qualification, can it be either upstream or downstream? I thought by default it is downstream, just like "dependent"? (3) Does the definition of a dependency being propagated assume a dependency cycle. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/761586?comment1452580_761592#comment1452580_761592

Comment: (1) Yes. (2) Without qualification, when I say “B is an immediate dependency of A”, B is upstream of A. I find it clearer to say “A depends on B” rather than use upstream/downstream terminology for dependencies. (3) No.

Comment: What I find confusing is that the arrow is opposite of the propagation of change? (if C change, it impacts B and then A, but the arrow (repesenting "dependencies-stream" but not "change/impact") go the other way around?).

Comment: @OlivierDulac yes, I agree that it’s confusing. The natural description of dependencies goes one way, changes go the opposite way...

Comment: About (3), the link says "A dependency is said to be propagated when some of its other-transitive (non-immediate) downstream dependencies also need it as an immediate dependency". Do you think that "need it as an immediate dependency" actually means "need it as an immediate **upstream** dependency", instead of "need it as an immediate **downstream** dependency"? Is that why you think that there is no cycle of dependency involved in the definition of propagation?

Comment: Yes, “need it as an immediate dependency” means “as an immediate upstream dependency”. Propagation looks down the tree, but at each node it looks back to see if the initial dependency is also an immediate upstream dependency of the current node. This means there are multiple paths between dependencies, but the result isn’t a cycle because the graph is directed.

Comment: @StephenKitt : you are correct writing that the graph is direct. To be solved It must necessarily be. However… as depicted into the page OP linked to… it **can** be understood as a transitive closure (=> pseudo cycle).