# How are host, build and target platforms of packages defined, with respect to dependencies?

Tags: package-management, dependencies

https://www.uber.com/blog/bootstrapping-ubers-infrastructure-on-arm64-with-zig/ says:

> A host is the machine that is compiling the binary. A target is the
> machine that will run the binary. In native compilation the host and
> target are the same platform (i.e., operating system, processor
> architecture, and shared libraries are the same).

https://nixos.org/manual/nixpkgs/stable/#ssec-stdenv-dependencies-reference says:

> Dependencies can be broken down along three axes: **their host and
> target platforms relative to the new derivation’s**, and whether they
> are propagated. The platform distinctions are motivated by cross
> compilation; see Cross-compilation for exactly what each platform
> means. [1] But even if one is not cross compiling, the platforms imply
> whether or not the dependency is needed at run-time or build-time, a
> concept that makes perfect sense outside of cross compilation. By
> default, the run-time/build-time distinction is just a hint for mental
> clarity, but with strictDeps set it is mostly enforced even in the
> native case.
>
> The extension of PATH with dependencies, alluded to above, proceeds
> according to the relative platforms alone. **The process is carried out
> only for dependencies whose host platform matches the new derivation’s
> build platform i.e. dependencies which run on the platform where the
> new derivation will be built.** [2] For each dependency  of those
> dependencies, dep/bin, if present, is added to the PATH environment
> variable.
>
> A dependency is said to be propagated when some of its
> other-transitive (non-immediate) downstream dependencies also need it
> as an immediate dependency. [3]
>
> It is important to note that **dependencies are not necessarily
> propagated as the same sort of dependency that they were before**, **but
> rather as the corresponding sort so that the platform rules still line
> up**. **To determine the exact rules for dependency propagation, we start
> by assigning to each dependency a couple of ternary numbers (-1 for
> build, 0 for host, and 1 for target) representing its dependency type,
> which captures how its host and target platforms are each “offset”
> from the depending derivation’s host and target platforms.** The
> following table summarize the different combinations that can be
> obtained: ...

The first quote defines the host and target platforms of a package as where it is built and run.

But when reading the second quote, I couldn't comprehend

> The process is carried out
> only for dependencies whose host platform matches the new derivation’s
> build platform i.e. dependencies which run on the platform where the
> new derivation will be built.

Does it mean that the host platforms of dependencies are defined as where they are run?, and the build platform of the new derivation is where it is built?

Are host platform and build platform the same concept? If yes, why does the second quote make distinction between them?

Thanks.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77495377/1081936

Answer (score 1):

Let's say host B (of platform type A) is building software X for platform type Y.

Now, B is the *build host* and A would be the *build platform*. This will be true for all the sub-parts of this build project.

Software X can have two types of dependencies: *run-time dependencies* and *build-time dependencies*. But the build-time dependencies can be further divided into two subclasses:

- Things that need to run on the build host as part of the build process, i.e. source code pre-processors and similar tools. These need to be suitable for running on platform A.
- Things that will become parts of software X, e.g. code libraries that will be linked statically, or data that will be incorporated into the resulting software package. If any executable code is in this category, it will need to be suitable for running on platform Y. Some things of this subclass may actually be platform-independent, like some library header files and other data items.

When platform A is equal to platform Y, both of these sub-types can be resolved the same way: just build a tree of dependencies, then start from the leaves and proceed towards the root.

But when A is not equal to Y, you'll also need to keep track of which sub-type each build-time dependency is.

Now, each of these build-time dependencies may have dependencies of its own. So the builder may find that in order to build software X for platform Y, it first needs to build a tool T for itself... and in order to build tool T for platform A, it first needs to satisfy the build dependencies for it, which may result in a chain of building tool T3 for platform A to build another tool T2 for platform A to ... ultimately build the software X.

The second sub-class of build-time dependencies needs to be cross-built: if our software X needs a static library L, then the build host will need to first get or build a version of L for platform type Y. But library L will have its own set of build-time dependencies, possibly *of both sub-types*: to build library L for platform Y, the build host may first have to build tool T2 for itself (platform A), and a library L2 that will be used as part of library L, so L2 must be also built for platform Y.

The automated build process must track all these dependencies, *each iterated to arbitrary depth*. Ideally it should also figure out that if a particular tool T is needed for building multiple software components that are part of the overall build, it should be built just once and kept until all the software components requiring that tool are built.

So, the autobuilder starts by building the build-time dependencies one by one to get to the point where it can finally build software X. Each individual component build operation will have *host platform* A and a *target platform* of either A or Y depending on which subclass of a build-time dependency it is.

Once software X is completely built, it may carry with it some metadata that says effectively "built on host B (of platform A) for platform type Y". In other words, this particular built instance of software X has *build host* B and *target platform* Y.

The *build platform* (A) should generally not be significant at this point, unless there is a need to track down a build error that only happens when using a specific tool on a specific architecture.

In software projects, the documentation is usually written with a maximum of only one cross-building step in mind: *host platform* is equivalent to *build platform*: both refer to the platform that built/is building/will build the executable, and *target platform* refers to the platform the executable-under-construction will run on.

Once the executable is built, you can stop thinking about how it was built, and start thinking about what you can do with it. If the executable is a cross-compiler, the host and target platform terms get recycled for the next step:

- the platform that built the cross-compiler is now just a historical detail with no particular name
- the platform that the new cross-compiler will run on will now be called the *host platform*
- and the platform the new cross-compiler will produce executables for will be the *target platform*

I don't think there is a wide-spread industry standard term for the "ultimate" target platform for the case where you are cross-compiling a cross-compiler.

But the Nixpkgs build system is prepared to handle the case of cross-compiling a cross-compiler, so **when you are speaking about Nixpkgs specifically**, [they specify the various platform terms as follows](https://nixos.org/manual/nixpkgs/stable/#ssec-cross-platform-parameters):

- *build platform* = the platform that built/builds/will build the executable(s)-under-construction
- *host platform* = the platform the executable(s)-under-construction will run on
- *target platform* = applies only to things that generate executable code; the platform the executable-under-construction will eventually build executable code for; the ultimate target platform.

Comment: Thanks. "Each individual component build operation will have host platform A and a target platform of either A or Y depending on which subclass of a build-time dependency it is. ... The build platform (A) should generally not be significant at this point". Are host platform and build platform synonyms? In the source of my quote, they seem to be different concepts.

Comment: They are very close, but the difference might be nuanced: *build platform* is used either in terms of a specific build project, or in the past tense as "the platform used to build this particular binary". If you are talking about cross-compiling cross-compilers, the term *host platform* may refer to something different. For a contrived example, one might cross-build on Apple Silicon (ARM) a cross-compiler that will run on x86 and produce code for some embedded architecture. Then the resulting cross-compiler will have build platform = ARM, host platform = x86 and target platform = whatever.

Comment: (1) In the contrived example, is the target platform "some embedded architecture"? Basically there are two levels of compilation involved, host platform and target platform both mean the platforms where some applications are run, but the former refer to the lower level, and the latter to the higher level?  (2) If I may also ask, are you able to understand the table in my next post https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/761888/how-should-this-table-of-dependencies-be-read?

Comment: (1) yes, the comment length limit forced me to shorten the last sentence. Usually each level of compilation is considered on its own, so the host and target platform terms are specific to each level. The compiler does not need to know or care about the fact that it's compiling a (cross-)compiler, so for the first compiler, the ultimate target platform of the compiler-under-construction is just generic build-time configuration data. See my edit above. (2) It's about handling the various kinds of dependencies as I wrote above, but I can't say I understand it fully yet. Thinking...