# How should this table of dependencies be read?

Tags: package-management, dependencies, nixos, nix

https://nixos.org/manual/nixpkgs/stable/#ssec-stdenv-dependencies-reference says

> A dependency is said to be propagated when some of its
> other-transitive (non-immediate) downstream dependencies also need it
> as an immediate dependency. [3]
>
> It is important to note that dependencies are not necessarily
> propagated as the same sort of dependency that they were before, but
> rather as the corresponding sort so that the platform rules still line
> up. To determine the exact rules for dependency propagation, we start
> by assigning to each dependency a couple of ternary numbers (-1 for
> build, 0 for host, and 1 for target) representing its dependency type,
> which captures how its host and target platforms are each “offset”
> from the depending derivation’s host and target platforms. The
> following table summarize the different combinations that can be
> obtained:
>
> ```
> host → target         attribute name          offset
> build --> build       depsBuildBuild          -1, -1
> build --> host        nativeBuildInputs       -1, 0
> build --> target      depsBuildTarget         -1, 1
> host --> host         depsHostHost            0, 0
> host --> target       buildInputs             0, 1
> target --> target     depsTargetTarget        1, 1
> ```

I was wondering how to read the table?

What do the arrows in "host → target" and "build --> build" mean?

How are the offsets calculated?

Comment: Just realized you cross posted on stackexchange (next time, please write it somewhere so that people do not spend time to answer if an answer is already given elsewhere). For reference, here is my answer there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77515761/how-should-this-table-of-platforms-of-dependencies-be-read

Answer (score 1):

In the context of Nix package management, dependencies between packages can be understood as a network of relationships. Let's break it down:

**1. Dependency Axes:**

- **Platform Relationships:** Think of different computer systems or platforms like Windows, Mac, and Linux. A program might need different things to run smoothly on each.
- **Propagation:** This is like a chain reaction. Sometimes, if Package A needs Package B, and then Package C needs Package A, Package C indirectly needs Package B too.

**2. Understanding Host and Target Platforms:**

- **Host Platform:** It's like the native environment where a package is being built.
- **Target Platform:** It's the environment where the package will run.

**3. Table Explanation with Examples:**

Let's imagine you're building a program called "CoolApp" on a Mac (your host platform). This program needs different libraries to work correctly. The table helps us understand which libraries are needed and how they're related in terms of platforms.

- **"build --> build" (depsBuildBuild, -1, -1):** Imagine CoolApp needing some specific libraries that are also used during its building process. They're like building blocks required only during the creation of CoolApp.
- **"build --> host" (nativeBuildInputs, -1, 0):** These could be tools or libraries needed during the building process of CoolApp but specific to the Mac environment.
- **"build --> target" (depsBuildTarget, -1, 1):** These might be libraries required during CoolApp's building that are meant for running the app on a different platform, like Linux.
- **"host --> host" (depsHostHost, 0, 0):** Imagine CoolApp needing some libraries specifically for Mac to run. They're like friends who also live in the Mac world.
- **"host --> target" (buildInputs, 0, 1):** These could be additional libraries CoolApp needs to run on another platform, like Linux.
- **"target --> target" (depsTargetTarget, 1, 1):** These might be libraries required for running CoolApp on Linux, which might not be needed during its building process on Mac.

**4. Real-World Implications:**

Understanding these dependencies helps the Nix package manager set up the environment properly. It ensures that when CoolApp is built on a Mac and then used on Linux, it has everything it needs to run smoothly in both places without any missing pieces.

So, this table is like a roadmap, guiding the package manager on which pieces (libraries or dependencies) should be included and where they fit in the puzzle to make sure CoolApp works perfectly on different platforms.

Comment: Looking at [another table on Nixpkgs dependencies](https://nixos.org/manual/nixpkgs/stable/#ssec-cross-dependency-categorization) later in the same document, and the explanation below that table, it seems to me the descriptious of `depsBuildBuild` and `nativeBuildInputs` should be the other way around: `depsBuildBuild` are build-time tools, and `nativeBuildInputs` are building blocks for the build process. [The Nixpkgs build, host and target terms](https://nixos.org/manual/nixpkgs/stable/#ssec-cross-platform-parameters) are also subtly different from what you might be used to.